# PHP: managed to store date into mysql, but the result shows different date value

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code to receive a user information and store them into MySQL database.

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $str_birthday) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted_password"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $dob = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($str_birthday));
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, birthday, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$dob', '$salt', NOW())");

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {

        // get user details
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

        // return user details
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here the format of the `$str_birthday` is something like `07/14/1982`. But when I opened the MySQL database, the `birthday` value turns out to be `1969-12-31` instead of `1982-07-14`.

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be input in YYYY-MM-DD format, convert your date to that format before inserts/updates

Comment: And as you're using MySQLi, use prepared statements/bind variables to avoid the risk of SQL injection

Comment: @MarkBaker Mark thank you for your tip. I'll modify the code for avoiding the risks of SQL injection. Now I changed my question a little bit so can you please check this out again?

Comment: try using DateTime::createFromFormat, replace with   _$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $str)->format('Y-m-d');_

Comment: @David I tried this before, and it says that it's an undefined method..

Comment: what PHP version do you use? DateTime::createFromFormat available from PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

Comment: @David mine is 5.5.29.

Comment: Is your database column type `DATE()`?